# How can I call unscoped functions in eval without using "this"

Tags: javascript, node.js

This works:

```js
import isValidDocument from './isValidDocument'

class Test {
  constructor() {
    Object.assign(this, { isValidDocument})
  }

  execute(person) {
    const evalResult = eval('this.isValidDocument(person)')
    console.log("Eval Result:", evalResult)
  }
}
```

but this doesn't:

```js
// ...
execute(person) {
  const evalResult = eval('isValidDocument(person)')
  console.log("Eval Result:", evalResult)
}
// ...
```

Basically, i want to be able to call the functions without using the `this` keyword.

How can I achieve that?

---

##### If you want context

I have rules (js expressions) stored in a database and i need it to execute them dinamically, the functions are fixed but the expressions can change.

Expression example: `isValidDocument(person) && person.age > 18`

The user will be able to change the expressions.

Yeah, i know about the security issue and i also accept suggestions to isolate the env. Currently, the expressions are made using blocks on the frontend and then the backend converts them to actual javascript statements, but the plan is to allow the user to create his own expressions directly.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea.

Comment: yeah, is better to assign the person and/or any other vars which you want to compare then use vm's [runInNewContext](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#scriptruninnewcontextcontextobject-options)

Comment: @kindall - No, it isn't. `eval` is spooky and runs in the context where you call it, including the value of `this`.

Comment: You can use Deno to execute in isolated (sandboxed) processes with no permissions.

Comment: ***I would strongly urge you not to do this.*** Instead, codify your rules into a structure you can process **without** allowing people to type in arbitrary code that will be run inside your server (!!!). It's *possible* to do it in loose mode (`class` code is always in strict mode, as is ESM module code) via the deprecated `with` statement. It's not a good idea, `with` is deprecated for a reason.